# Google Play open beta searchability issue

Tags: android, google-play

Google states the following regrading there open beta service "For early access apps (new apps that haven't been published to production): Users can find your beta version via search on the Play Store. Once users find your listing, they can install your app normally."

[Source](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

I published my app to open beta last night but when I log out of any google related service and search on the play store my app is not visible. It is titled Fractal Plus. The opt-in URL seems to work fine.

https://play.google.com/apps/testing/biz.MagiTek.FractalPlus

Anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Early Access' feature on the Play Store may still be being rolled out to users. On one of my devices the play store does not have an Early Access section yet and I cannot see your app via a search, however on another device I am able to see your app in the play store search results.

[image: Play store image]

Comment: Ahhhh makes scenes. Thanks for the info. If you would like to view a trailer for the game it can be accessed from my website http://MagiTek.biz